# Custom push notification sounds outside main bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

In application I'm developing I have a requirement that user can customise push notification sounds server-side. I checked [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6) and it states that 
"The sound files can be in the main bundle of the client app or in the Library/Sounds folder of the app’s data container."

So I'm putting sounds I download from back-end to this subfolder in Library, which I create like this:

```
+ (NSString *)soundFolderPath
{
   NSString* path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];

    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sounds"];

    NSLog(@"%@: Path to sounds folder: %@", [self class], path);

   return path;
}
- (void)createSoundsDirectoryIfNeeded
{
    NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString* path = [self.class soundFolderPath];

    if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {
        NSError* error = nil;

        [manager createDirectoryAtPath:path withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

        if (error) {
            [self handleError:error];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I send push notification, while app is in background - it plays default notification sound instead of a custom one. I've checked data container of the app - files exist and are in the correct folder. File format conforms to what is described in documentation and I even added those sounds as resources to bundle and that way it actually worked.

I can't find a solution to this and at this point I'm wondering if it's even possible.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you fix your problem? Maybe it is related to my problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998278/change-push-notification-sound-file-only-works-after-ios-reboot

Comment: Well from what I've read and understood - you actually can't have iOS playing files from somewhere else, other than application bundle, so we decided to scrap the feature for now. Only solution is - if you're using ad-hoc distribution - you can go against apple restrictions and have player to play sounds in-app in background, but there's a lot of fiddling associated with that. I can elaborate, if you're interested.

Comment: I figured out, that it is possible to play sounds from Libary/Sounds, but you can set the file only once. If you exchange the file (with the same name) you have to reinstall you app, or reboot you device.

Comment: @patrickS : It happens with me too. When I am exchanging any sound file with Library/Sound/notification.caf file, when app is in background there is no sound. When i restart the device it works for updated tone. do you know any solution for not restarting device?

Comment: No, but I have opened a radar