# Change push notification sound file, only works after iOS reboot

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, push-notification

I have problem with an iOS app access a file in the `Library/Sounds` directory.

My iOS app delivers different sound files in the main app bundle. I have written some code which copies a selected file into the `Library/Sounds` directory. It always has the same name (`foo.caf`) in that directory.

This way I am able to switch to different push notification sounds. If I do this the first time everything works fine. But if I switch to an other app and I receive a push notification there is no sound anymore. Also the default sound isn't played. But the strange thing is, that if I reboot the iPhone and I receive a new push notification I get the newly selected sound..

Does iOS have some cache or something else, which I have to reset first? Or is this an iOS bug?

**EDIT:**

I have written a small demo project to reproduce the problem. It can be found at:

Source code: https://github.com/patricks/PushNotificationSoundSwitch/releases

Git Repo: https://github.com/patricks/PushNotificationSoundSwitch

Readme file: https://github.com/patricks/PushNotificationSoundSwitch/blob/master/README.md

Comment: My thought is that the OS catalogs the possible push clips on startup.  Does kill/launching the app have the same effect as OS restart?

Also - you don't actually have to copy a file to Library/Sounds to utilize it as a push notification sound.  But obviously you're doing this to handle the dynamic nature of the sound being used.  However, I'm curious to know if any of the files in your bundle have that same name (foo.caf) or if you just rename when copying to the Sounds directory.  This wouldn't explain the lack of sound, but I could see it causing some strangeness.

Comment: You are right i am coping to handle the different file names. No there is no other foo.caf and killing/launching the app doesn't help. Only the reboot works. The strange thing is, if I copy back the first .caf file (incl. renaming) the push sound works again... This is so confusing.

Comment: Sounds like iOS must catalog the eligible audio files on install (of an app) or restart of the OS.  Not entirely sure why copying the file back would work, but perhaps it looks at the size as well as the name for some reason.  Any reason you can't push this decision server side and just use the unique name of each file?

Comment: Yes there is a problem, I use Parse as push service an I send the message to different channels.

Comment: I have updated this question and added a sample project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why can't you just send me the infos what you did?